# Installing specific version of ansible from PPA

Tags: apt, ppa

trying to install ansible 1.9 on a server.  I've got the ansible-1.9 PPA installed.  Here's the relevant info on my last attempt:

```
root@host:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# ll
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 26 13:44 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Aug 26 13:40 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  142 Aug 26 13:40 ansible-ansible-1_9-trusty.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   87 Aug 26 13:40 deb_thehost_org.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   87 Aug 26 10:32 deb_thehost_org.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   69 Aug 26 13:40 mirrors_dev_company_com_java_java_ubuntu.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   69 Aug 26 10:32 mirrors_dev_company_com_java_java_ubuntu.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Aug 26 13:40 mirrors_dev_company_com_zabbix_3_0_ubuntu.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Aug 26 10:32 mirrors_dev_company_com_zabbix_3_0_ubuntu.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   75 Aug 26 13:40 packages_elasticsearch_org_logstashforwarder_debian.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   75 Aug 26 10:32 packages_elasticsearch_org_logstashforwarder_debian.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  377 Aug 26 13:40 puppetlabs-pc1.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  377 Aug 26 10:32 puppetlabs-pc1.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Aug 26 13:40 repo_dev_company_com.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Aug 26 10:32 repo_dev_company_com.list.save
root@host:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-cache madison ansible
   ansible | 1.9.6-1ppa~trusty | http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible-1.9/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
   ansible | 1.7.2+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1 | https://mirrors.dev.company.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
   ansible | 1.5.4+dfsg-1 | https://mirrors.dev.company.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
   ansible | 1.5.4+dfsg-1 | https://mirrors.dev.company.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Sources
   ansible | 1.7.2+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1 | https://mirrors.dev.company.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe Sources
root@host:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get install ansible=1.9.6-1ppa~trusty --dry-run
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-crypto python-httplib2 python-jinja2 python-markupsafe
  python-paramiko python-support sshpass
Suggested packages:
  python-crypto-dbg python-crypto-doc python-jinja2-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ansible python-crypto python-httplib2 python-jinja2 python-markupsafe
  python-paramiko python-support sshpass
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Inst python-support (1.0.15 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Inst python-markupsafe (0.18-1build2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst python-jinja2 (2.7.2-2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Inst python-crypto (2.6.1-4build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst python-paramiko (1.10.1-1git1build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Inst python-httplib2 (0.8-2build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Inst sshpass (1.05-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Inst ansible (1.9.6-1ppa~trusty ansible-1.9:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf python-support (1.0.15 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf python-markupsafe (0.18-1build2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf python-jinja2 (2.7.2-2 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf python-crypto (2.6.1-4build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf python-paramiko (1.10.1-1git1build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf python-httplib2 (0.8-2build1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [all])
Conf sshpass (1.05-1 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf ansible (1.9.6-1ppa~trusty ansible-1.9:14.04/trusty [all])
root@host:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get install ansible=1.9.6-1ppa~trusty
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-crypto python-httplib2 python-jinja2 python-markupsafe
  python-paramiko python-support sshpass
Suggested packages:
  python-crypto-dbg python-crypto-doc python-jinja2-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ansible python-crypto python-httplib2 python-jinja2 python-markupsafe
  python-paramiko python-support sshpass
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,235 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,827 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package python-support.
(Reading database ... 124674 files and directories currently installed.)

...

Setting up ansible (1.9.6-1ppa~trusty) ...
Processing triggers for python-support (1.0.15) ...
root@host:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# ansible --version
ansible 2.1.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

What am I missing?  Is this an issue w/the Ansible PPA, or have I missed a step somewhere?

Comment: Assuming this PPA https://launchpad.net/~ansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible-1.9 all you need is `sudo apt-get install  ansible` the PPA only has version 1.9

Comment: Also, if you still have an issue, did you have  2.1.1.0 installed first? You must purge that `sudo apt purge ansible` before you can install an older version.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but the answers to your questions/points are in the console sequence that I pasted in the OP.  Except for the question about purging, which yes, I did.

Comment: @Travis What is the output of `apt-cache policy ansible`? It's not in the OP

Comment: @Anwar - here's the result; similar to the apt-cache madison output: `root@foreman:~# apt-cache policy ansible
ansible:
  Installed: 1.9.6-1ppa~trusty
  Candidate: 1.9.6-1ppa~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 1.9.6-1ppa~trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible-1.9/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.7.2+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 https://mirrors.dev.company.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     1.5.4+dfsg-1 0
        500 https://mirrors.dev.company.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages`

Comment: Followed by this: `root@foreman:~# ansible --version
ansible 2.1.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides`

Comment: @Travis the output shows that you really installed ansible 1.9.6, not 2.1.1

Comment: @anwar - even though Ansible --version shows 2.1.1.0?

Comment: @Travis remove ansible first using `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove ansbile` and what is the output of `which ansible`?

Comment: @Anwar
`root@foreman:~# apt-get --purge autoremove ansible
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ansible* python-crypto* python-httplib2* python-jinja2* python-markupsafe*
  python-paramiko* python-support* sshpass*
...
(Reading database ... 125511 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ansible (1.9.6-1ppa~trusty) ...
Purging configuration files for ansible (1.9.6-1ppa~trusty) ...
...
root@foreman:~# which ansible
/usr/local/bin/ansible
root@foreman:~# ansible --version
ERROR! Unexpected Exception: No module named markupsafe`

Comment: @Travis Now install the ansible 1.9.6 again. Since the old config files are gone (hopefully)

Comment: @Anwar - I'm going to remove these files first: `root@foreman:/usr/local/bin# ll
total 168
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 25 15:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Jul 31  2015 ../
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4200 Aug 25 15:06 ansible*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4200 Aug 25 15:06 ansible-console*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4200 Aug 25 15:06 ansible-doc*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4200 Aug 25 15:06 ansible-galaxy*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4200 Aug 25 15:06 ansible-playbook*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4200 Aug 25 15:06 ansible-pull*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4200 Aug 25 15:06 ansible-vault*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue turned out to be droppings leftover from previous (unintentional) 2.1.1.0 installation that are not removed with an "apt-get purge."  Anyone else experiencing this issue should check: /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages for anything ansible-related post-purge.  I was able to get the correct version installed by starting w/a fresh Ubuntu instance, but you should have no trouble if you clear out whatever may be leftover.

Comment: I'm using WSL, and I found stuff under /home/me/.local/....